# Java timer doesn't run when using JNA call to Win32 WaitForSingleObject()

Tags: java, jna

I'm trying to terminate the JNA call to `WaitForSignleObject()` with `Timer` that interrupts the current thread:

```
final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    thread.interrupt();
  }
}, 3000);

try {               
  Kernel32.INSTANCE.WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, Kernel32.INFINITE);
  ...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

The problem is that `TimerTask.run()` is not called after 3 seconds have passed as expected, it's called only after `WaitForSingleObject()` exits itself. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `run()` is not called, or it's just `InterruptedException` not throw?

Comment: Yes, I verified that with a breakpoint put in run()

Comment: That's quite strange, have you tried to verify it by other means?

Comment: @axtavt, the code in run() interrupts the current thread, i.e. does exactly nothing.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake while writing the code here. Originally, the correct thread is interrupted.

Comment: @axtavt, I verified, and run() method is really called, but the thread is not interrupted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread interruption mechanism is a Java-specific feature, so it's no surprise that native code doesn't respect it.

If all you need is a timeout, you can use the second argument of `WaitForSingleObject()` instead. If you need more complex logic, you can [create an event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to notify waiting thread about interruption, and use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on that event and your `hProcess`.

Comment: You probably want to use whatever mechanism Windows provides for causing a WaitForXXX method to return (depends on the mutex object, e.g. "TerminateProcess" for the usage with hProcess in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few mistakes in that simple code;

- During `run()` the code interrupts the current calling thread - useless, you want the thread making the native call.
- You need to handle the interruption of the native call itself.

Below link to how to properly handle from the java side. 
[Detecting thread interruption with JNA native wait call (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889161/detecting-thread-interruption-with-jna-native-wait-call-windows)

On WinAPI side: depending on your case you may need CloseHandle, SetEvent or whatever notification you need.
Then after returning from WaitForSingleObject check the object state and throw InterruptedException if you have to.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the code directly here, and didn't pay an attention that wrong thread is interrupted. Originally, the code looks more like this after the edit I did.

Comment: I've tried using `AbstractInterruptibleChannel`, but this doesn't help in my case, since the thread is still not interrupted. This abstract class may be useful to cleanup system resources on thread interruption, but I can't make this interruption work.

Comment: Right!AIC can help to handle interrupt() from java and signal the native call, i.e. adhering to Java API. Of course it doesn't do anything on its own. You should follow the second part on WinAPI, either close process handle via `TerminateProcess(handle, exitCode)` if that's an external process the thread awaits, or do whatever it takes to exit the WaitForSingleObject. Either way you have to use WinAPI function to make release the waiting thread. Java can't just handle the task for you via Thread.interrupt. It has been over a decade I did WinAPI code but if you post some more code I might help.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at Microsoft's documentation for [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there's a suggestion that you might to think about WaitForSingleObjectEx instead (in order to enter an "alertable wait state").

Comment: It's a workaround to pass the timeout value to WaitForSingleObjectEx(), and I didn't want to use it in the first place, since it breaks my API :) (I wrap windows process handle into java.lang.Process)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that TimerTask.run() is not called after 3 seconds have
>   passed as expected, it's called only after WaitForSingleObject() exits
>   itself. What am I doing wrong?

The simple answer: You're making a blocking call to the operating system.  While your thread is blocked, a TimerTask in that thread will not fire.

Even if you ran the TimerTask on another thread, it is unlikely the interrupt would work, since Thread.interrupt is a Java specific feature (as was pointed out by @axtavt).

If you would like more help, please create another posting and explain why you need to do this and what your constraints are (something more specific than "...it breaks my API").  Perhaps we'll be to find an alternative approach.

Comment: The timer will run its tasks on a thread different from the current one (i.e. the thread that is blocking).  There's not an obvious reason why it wouldn't trigger (and failing to hit a breakpoint set on "run" is not an ironclad guarantee that it did *not* run).  However, the native function is in no way bound to do *anything* in response to a Java thread interrupt.

Comment: If so, then the simple answer is you're trying to interrupt the wrong thread: the code says `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` but the API call is on a different thread.

Comment: @jdigital, please see my edit, I've corrected the code. Originally, the code was correct, and it was calling interrupt() on the correct thread.