# Thread freezes on readUTF from empty DataInputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Only one thread is creating. Under certain circumstances it needs to be shut down.
In this case it can be done by checking `isInterrupted()`. But it freezes on `in.readUTF()` if there is empty InputStream. How this can be fixed?

```
DataInputStream in;
....
public void stop() {
thread.interrupt();
}

public void run() {
     while(true) {
           String str = in.readUTF();  // locking here, when stream is empty
           S.o.p(str)
           if(isInterrupted) {
           return;
        }}
}

public void main(String args[]) {
      Thread thread = new Thread();       
}
```

Comment: You have to either: interrupt the thread. close the stream, set socket.setSoTimeout (if working w/ sockets) or any other timeout available (which is likely to translate to that at some point)... or just go for non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot interrupt a blocked InputStream. (This is one of the differences with NIO)  You can instead close the stream before calling interrupt and this will trigger an IOException.

```
public void stop() {
    in.close(); // or use something like IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: not every stream would support asynch. closing and if they do support they SHOULD support thread interrupt as well. Anyone can install an asynch handler to thread.interrupt

Comment: @bestsss I have looked at using an asynch handler but it appears to be a black art (using internal only APIs) Do you know any articles on how to use this with puplic use APIs?

Comment: yeah. it's public, offical API, I even posted on SO once. Need to find it. Anyways: *java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.implCloseChannel*. Weirdly placed but it's an official API. No, java secrets or reflection. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889161/detecting-thread-interruption-with-jna-native-wait-call-windows

Comment: @bestsss maybe you can provide example of using asynch handler in this case?

Comment: @PeterLawrey after this attempt isAlive states, that this thread is still functioning.

Comment: The thread is still functioning if you catch the IOException and continue.

Comment: @PeterLawrey and how can I properly shut this thread down in IOException handling?

Comment: Assuming you are catching the IOException, you can return from the run() method.

Comment: @Condor, you do not need async handler in this case if close() works and you can control it. Side note: generally, a thread exits when it leaves the run() method.

Comment: Btw, `interrupt()` should be called prior `close()`, otherwise the exit clause (if relies on interrupted flag) may not properly work, i.e. there is a race.